# Getting a set of a list from a list of strings

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"c1":["[\"text\",\"text2\"]","[\"bla\",\"bla\",\"bla\"]"]})
```

and I'm removind `[]` and `""` :

```
df["c2"] = df["c1"].apply(lambda x:re.sub('[\["\]]', "", x))
```

then I want to add `df['c2']` to a list:

```
list = df['c2'].to_list()
```

Then I get this:  `['text,text2', 'bla,bla,bla']`

So far so good.  But then I want a list with only unique values, what I could to using `set(list)`.

The proble is that Instead of `['text,text2', 'bla,bla,bla']` I needed to get `['text','text2', 'bla','bla','bla']` so when I apply `set(list) I would get **what I am expecting:**

`['text','text2','bla']`

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use `list` as a variable. Second, once you get `['text,text2',...]` you can use `str.split`. So your set would be

```
{y for x in df['c2'].str.split(',') for y in x}
```

Output:

```
{'bla', 'text', 'text2'}
```

**Note**: You can use regex directly to extract all patterns between the `\"`:

```
set(df['c1'].str.extractall('\"([^"]+)\"')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new = []
for l in list:
    new.extend(l.split(',') )
new = list(set(new))
```

which results in `new` to be

```
['text2', 'text', 'bla']
```